# Typescript: how to sort an array, case insensitively?

Tags: arrays, sorting, typescript

I am trying to sort an array in typescript case insensitively. In javascript, that could be accomplished with

```
    list.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });
```

In typescript the sort looks like

```
    list.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a > b) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a < b) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
```

Starting with [F, E, D, c, b, a] I expect to get [a, b, c, D, E, F]

The javascript sort delivers the expected results, but the typescript sort returns [D, E, F, a, b, c]. How do I make the typescript sort case insensitive?

EDIT: the reason I can't use the javascript method is because in typescript a and b are boolean and don't have ,toLowerCase() method

Comment: Why can you not use the JavaScript approach in Typescript?

Comment: any valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript (almost ..)

Comment: I don't know why that comment keeps getting upvoted. Did you actually implement it and see if you can use the JavaScript approach in Typescript? It fails because of type checking. It won't work. I suspect the reason for the question was because the OP actually tried it.

Comment: in typescript .sort(a, b) a and b are boolean so I cant use a.toLowerCase()

Comment: The solution appears to be behind a pay wall https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-case-insensitive-sorting-for-string-arrays

Comment: If Typescript is claiming a and b are booleans, looks to me like the types are declared incorrectly in your example. It wouldn't make sense if they were actually booleans.

Comment: The solution is below. But you can't leave part of it out and expect it to work. The output in my answer was copied from a successful run of your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sort function. It's basically a rewrite of what you have but it may be a bit cleaner. It also works. The compiler wants a type. It doesn't care if it's `string` or `any` in this case. I have updated the answer to change the types passed in into strings. It works for this array as easily well as type `any`.

```
function sortStrings(a: string, b: string) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
}

console.log(['F', 'E', 'D', 'c', 'b', 'a'].sort(sortStrings));
```

Output:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'D', 'E', 'F' ]
```

Comment: in typescript, the parameters a and b are boolean and don't have a .toLowerCase() method

Comment: Did you change the type to `any`? If you copy this code exactly it will work.  I wrote it like this for a reason.

Comment: You are correct. I still don't understand why the compiler wants a boolean there. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: It just wants a type. I have updated the answer to make the type `string`. Still works fine.